# How to solve InflateException at custom view

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, inflate-exception

My question is about Android/Java.

My main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <org.javaforum.input
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('SO - Please enter a correct E-Mail!!!')"
        android:hint="Enter your E-Mail"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My input.java:

```
public class input extends TextView{
    public input(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr, getIdentifier(context,attr));
        if(existsoninvalid(attr)){
            //Code
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean existsoninvalid(AttributeSet attr){
        for(int f=1; f<=attr.getAttributeCount(); f++){
            if(attr.getAttributeName(f)=="oninvalid"){//Here must be the error
                //Code
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        
    }
}
```

The app crashes with the Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{org.javaforum/org.javaforum.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML
> file line #7: Error inflating class org.javaforum.input

But when I remove this:

```
if(attr.getAttributeName(f)=="oninvalid"){//Here must be the error
        //Code
}
```

The app doesn't crash and I don't get any Exceptions. I don't know why. Where is the problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: I think something went wrong with ```getIdentifier(context,attr)``` please remove it from constructor , it will look like ```super(context, attr)``` and try again with `for loop` i.e. 
 **public static boolean existsoninvalid(AttributeSet attr){for(int f=0; f < attr.getAttributeCount(); f++){if(attr.getAttributeName(f).equals("oninvalid")){ return true; } } return false;}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception has a nested "caused by" exception with more details.

Indexing is zero based. Your for loop starts at 1 and goes off by one in the other end.

In addition, in Java use `equals()` and not `==` for string comparison. (This does not cause a crash but does not work the way you intend either.)

Comment: In this case I try to start the loop at 0 but I still get the app crashing. I tried also to access to the attributes with the AttributeSet.getAttributeName() method in other code and it seems to start at 1... So why I am still getting this exception?

Comment: Start at 0 and change the end condition from `<=` to `<` to avoid the off-by-one the end.